# Android: How to implement Calendar App that display only 1 day on screen

Tags: android, view, calendar, infinite-scroll, swipe-gesture

I want to have a simple app that display the current date. Say for now, the display of the app is FEB 10. Now, when I swipe to the right, it will display FEB 11. Every time I swipe to the right, the day displayed increase by 1. If I swipe it to the left, it will decrease by 1 day.

What's the best way to implement this? What views do you suggest in implementing this? The transition between the days should mimic the Gallery view.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either implement FlingListener by creating your own custom view, or use images and keep a counter for days and flip using viewflipper.